# Access macro call from vb script

Tags: vba, ms-access, vbscript

I have a VB Script that calls an MS Access DB, sets UserControl to True, runs a macro that runs to completion and then closes the database.  I get an error on the final line of the VB Script that pops up after the database closes:

> Script:  \Path\Script.vbs
>
> Line:  5 Char:  1
>
> Error:  The | action was canceled.
>
> Code:  800A09C5
>
> Source:  (null)

Again...the process does exactly what I want...I just don't want the error message to pop up when it completes.

The script:

```
Dim accessApp
Set accessApp = createObject("Access.Application")
accessApp.UserControl = True
accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase("\\DB_Path\Database.accdb")
accessApp.DoCmd.RunMacro "AutoRunAll"
```

Thoughts on how I can eliminate that final error message that occurs when the DB closes?  Everything else is working just as envisioned.

Thanks...Mark

Comment: So some code within the Access file is closing db itself? I tested this with Run for VBA procedure and get "Unknown runtime error 800A9C68" message. RunMacro kicks off different issues, first is an error within Access and when I okay that get script error "The RunMacro action was canceled." If I remove code from Access that closes db then everything works.

Comment: Yes...the code called by the macro in the Access DB closes the database when the process completes.  Once the DB closes...the VB Script error above then appears.  I suppose I could take out the "Application.Quit" statement at the end of the function the macro calls and let the VB Script close the database?  That might be an option...but I'm afraid it wouldn't allow the process to complete.

Comment: Won't know until you try. I tested with Access just opening a MsgBox. When I closed MsgBox, the script continued and closed Access. True, might not get same behavior with procedure that doesn't trigger box.

Comment: Update:  tried to take out the "Application.Quit" in the DB code and close the database from the vb script.  No dice...tries to close it during the code execution and throws an error in Access telling me the macro action was canceled.  Better off how it us where everything executes...then gives me the error I dismiss when it's done.

Comment: Try VBA instead of macro.

Comment: Moved the one "OpenForm" piece of the macro to the VBA...ran the script.  Everything processed as expected with the accessApp.Run where I called the function in the DB.  But I still got an error.  Slightly different...but a VB Script error box at the end.  Error was the same place. Code was 800A9C68.  Source was:  Microsoft VBScript runtime error.  So still throwing an error for some reason.  May not be worth worrying about since I'm getting what I need.  Just don't like the extra message saying something's wrong.

Comment: That should work. when you launch/open the Application, and double click on the AutoRunAll macro, does it work, and work without any prompts?

Comment: See my first comment. I got that error message when code was in Access to close db. Maybe you should just run code to open db and not declare and set Access objects in the script. Access would automatically execute the AutoRunAll macro by calling from an AutoExec macro. Or code behind a form set to open on default runs the macro. I have done that with VBScript running Shell command to open file.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions.  The simple way to overcome the superfluous error (or so it seems) was to just put an "On Error Resume Next" before the final vb script line.  I know it's not great programming, but I can't figure out what is throwing that error on a line of the script that is executed exactly as desired.  So now I call the script from task scheduler, it runs the ms access process to completion, and the database closes as requested...and no vbscript error is given.

Comment: Just make sure not left with an Access process still running in background. Check with Task Manager.

Comment: Yes...confirmed when I first didn't get the error that an Access process is not running.  Thanks!